C# .net8 Projet : the name 'propperjs' does not exist in the current context
here is the C# .net code that I am using for a project
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Project_911TicketSupport</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-M4x3pCeVQ9V-9DJaeK8k5A38ty4UOMXJAFj8L5hJvN5Y68f4SR8bDaI4+f6CEdU1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Project_911TicketSupport.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Project_911TicketSupport</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2024 - Project_911TicketSupport - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZvpUoO/+P/pzQhjbQbQ16MT+7+OfpHA4Fp0Qf/W0i+2kA+aG9Fyxst4qwKgjNfuw"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl7WXGC1g6a0AVsIGDxjAg9fWhK8RIeG0p/ETcFGBl3YYNoAn7B2N8ymq3I"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgKtE3/U2JpUbi5OMCf0zYyb3W0hPY4xAD4nA1v4U8AXO1AfeFK"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>

at the end of my code when I want to integrate propperjs I get the following error message "the name 'propperjs' does not exist does not exist in the current context"
How can I solve this?
thank you
I tried to change libraries, and check if my library was properly installed.
I understand why I have this error and how to solve it

What do you mean when you say "integrate properjs"? Could you provide a code sample please? Also, the issue you're describing doesn't seem to be c# or .net related related. This is straight up mvc/html.

View the rendered HTML, not the cshtml.  This will then include any rendered @section Scripts which appears to be where you're actually getting the error (that or site.js which is also not shown.   See [mcve].   The code you've provided boils down to just 3x script statements:  https://jsfiddle.net/2a0514nm/   Also check the error - is it popperjs or popper.js - not "proppper"?

@fdomn-m that might've come out wrong! I should've asked why the author assigned c#-8.0 tag, but the question is html/js related.

@AliKhakpouri ah, no worries - not sure the vs2022 tag applies either?

"I understand why I have this error and how to solve it" - If I'm reading this correctly, you're saying that you've already resolved this problem?!
